# How to converting GIT (ImageToText / image captioner ) model to ONNX format

Tags: deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, huggingface-transformers, onnx, onnxruntime

I want to convert  [GIT model](https://huggingface.co/microsoft/git-large)  to .ONNX

I've found a tool called  [Optimum](https://huggingface.co/docs/optimum/en/exporters/onnx/usage_guides/export_a_model) but it does not support GIT model architecture , It says You need to pass a custom ONNX config so it can convert GIT from .safetensors to .onnx and it is not able to do it natively, And the problem is I couldn't find any onnx config for it yet or any alternative solution.

this is the command I used for conversion.

```
optimum-cli export onnx --model test_LVM/image_captioning/GIT/CLIP/git-base-coco/  --task image-to-text git_onnx/
```

[optimum-cli error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wacGq.png)